# Solve L1 regression using scipy.linprog get ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (20,1) into shape (20)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-programming

I am trying to solve L1 regression using scipy.linprog but get an error.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from scipy.optimize import linprog


def generate_dataset(n, d):
    A, b, coef = datasets.make_regression(n_samples=n,
                                          n_features=d,
                                          n_informative=d,
                                          noise=10,
                                          coef=True,
                                          random_state=0)
    return A, b, coef



def solver(A, b):
    n = len(A)
    m = len(A[0])
    c = np.vstack((np.zeros((m, 1)), np.ones((n, 1))))
    A_ = np.vstack((np.hstack((A, -np.eye(n))), np.hstack((-A, -np.eye(n)))))
    b_ = np.vstack((b, -b))
    res = linprog(c, A_ub=A_, b_ub=b_)
    return res

A, b, coef = generate_dataset(10, 10)
res = solver(A, b)
print(res)
print(coef)
```

The generate_dataset function randomly generate dataset of 10 samples with 10 features, then I try to solve min|Ax-b|. This is a simple problem of solve least absolute deviation regression using linear programming. But an error occurs.
The error is `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (20,1) into shape (20)`. 
I think there must be something wrong with the dimension of some matrix but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Where does the error occur?  In the `linprog` call?  What is the `shape` of the 3 inputs to that function?

Comment: Why is `c` constructed as a (m+n,1) array?  Why not `(m+n,)`?

Comment: Consider switching to some other optimizer. linprog will not bring much joy (your corrected example will fail for just doubled dimensions). There are much better LP-solvers like GLPK, CBC and good modelling tools like cvxpy and pulp. It's also possible to use scipy.optimize.minimize with Cobyla or SLSQP if your data will not be that huge.

Answer (score 3):

Replace `c` with `np.squeeze(c)` in the following line:

```
res = linprog(c, A_ub=A_, b_ub=b_)
```

result:

```
  status: 0
   slack: array([  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   1.74947071e-15,   8.81121786e-15,
         3.08534221e+01,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00])
 success: True
     fun: 15.426711070042149
       x: array([  4.17175117e+01,   3.70399683e+01,   6.20756253e+01,
         3.77095189e+01,   7.52937664e+01,   6.83052169e+01,
         2.99644354e+01,   0.00000000e+00,   4.16154976e+00,
         1.57578313e+01,   0.00000000e+00,   1.45010519e-32,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         1.04491091e-15,   1.77635684e-15,   5.78946776e-16,
         0.00000000e+00,   1.54267111e+01])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nit: 19
[ 42.38550486  42.87687009  66.01735375  29.8282326   60.63932141
  61.8015429   30.15748167   1.91931983  13.54740642  29.00776072]
```